# Sentence English grammar with causative verb

Tags: sentence-construction, spoken-english, causatives

> My father asked my little brother to bring him the newspaper?

Rewrite the following sentence with causative verb?

Answer (score 1):

A causative verb means a verb with the meaning of causing something, or making something happen. According to [esl.about.com](http://esl.about.com/od/grammarstructures/a/causative.htm),

> There are three causative verbs in English: *Make*, *Have*, and *Get*."

(Wikipedia actually lists [many more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causative#Examples), but if you are doing this for an English homework assignment, they most likely want you to use one of the main three.)

All of these verbs can be used in a way that means "cause someone to do something":

> - make [someone] do [something]
> - have [someone] do [something]
> - get [someone] to do [something]

(Notice that get needs the word *to*.)

In your sentence, the father needs to cause *someone* (the little brother) to do *something* (bring him the newspaper).
So we can rephrase your sentence using any of these three verbs:

> My father made my little brother bring him the newspaper.
>
> My father had my little brother bring him the newspaper.
>
> My father got my little brother to bring him the newspaper.